# Implementing HTB, NetEM, and TBF traffic control simultaneously

Tags: traffic-shaping, tc, htb

I am working on a bash utility that will use several aspects of the tc Linux command line utility to emulate various network conditions.  I have successfully constructed several qdisc hierarchies, one each for HTB bandwidth control, NetEM delay and packet manipulation, and TBF rate control, as well as combined handlers for HTB-NetEM, and TBF-NetEM Where I am struggling is in combining the three into a single structure, for cases in which I need to control all of these factors on a single connection.  This is what I have so far:

```
  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface root handle 1:0 htb

  sudo tc class add dev $interface parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb  #htb args

  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface parent 1:1 handle 10:0 tbf  #tbf args

  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface parent 10:1 handle 101:0 netem  #netem args
```

Because of my smaller scope cases, I know that the problem does not lie in the syntax of my inputs, but likely in the structure of my tc qdiscs and classes.  When I attempt to run these commands together with rate and bandwidth shaping arguments (10 and 15 Mbit/s respectively) in *both* ethernet ports of my bridge, no change to the bandwidth of an iperf test is shown, in TCP or UDP.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Here are my other *working* compound structures, in case they might help:

HTB and NetEM:

```
  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface root handle 1: htb

  sudo tc class add dev $interface parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb  #htb args

  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface parent 1:1 handle 10:0 netem  #netem args
```

TBF and NetEM:

```
  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface root handle 1:0 tbf  #tbf args

  sudo tc qdisc add dev $interface parent 1:1 handle 10:0 netem  #netem args
```

Comment: [This Website](http://mytestbed.net/projects/omf/wiki/NetEM_examples_of_rules) is my primary source for my current method of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not HTB/TBF but HFSC.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tc-hfsc.7.html

You can attach netem to the leaf classes.

Here is a sample script to get you started..

```
#!/bin/bash
tc qdisc add dev veth1 parent root handle 1: hfsc default 11
tc class add dev veth1 parent 1: classid 1:1 hfsc sc rate 100mbit ul rate 100mbit
tc class add dev veth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 hfsc sc rate 50mbit
tc class add dev veth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 hfsc sc umax 1500 dmax 50ms rate 10mbit ul rate 10mbit
tc qdisc add dev veth1 parent 1:12 handle 12 netem delay 150ms
tc filter add dev veth1 parent 1: protocol ip u32 match ip sport 22 0xffff flowid 1:12
```

This creates a 100mbit class, 50mbit of which is in the default class (but can burst up to 100mbit) whilst the other class permits a realtime requirement so that 1500 byte packets must leave the queue within 50ms, the maximum rate of this class is 10mbit at all times.

Finally we added a leaf qdisc onto that class which actually delays packets leaving the queue by 150ms.

Traffic into the realtime class is selected on the basis of it having a source port 22 attribute (so all ssh traffic).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The source you've listed is pretty dense and poorly written, and I have only been working with traffic control for a week, so I'm not sure if I understand. Please correct me if I'm wrong in saying that the "sc rate __mbit" argument would control rate, while "ul rate __mbit" controls bandwidth.

Comment: "sc rate __mbit" controls the minimum provision whereas "ul rate __mbit" controls the maximum provision. So you at least get <sc rate> and at most get <ul rate>.

Comment: Ok, simple enough. The sample script works as far as I can tell.  I suppose I'm still confused about the simple concept of rate vs. bandwidth control when it comes to tc.  Are you saying that I don't need both, and that HFSC can be used for all effective control outside of NetEM?  Like I said, I'm new here and I appreciate your help!

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say that since I dont know every single type of service quality people might want. If you want a classful qdisc which supports both link sharing and real time delivery then this is a meaningful way to do it.